# Centos - How to recompile mysql with MYSQLI_NO_CHANGE_USER_ON_PCONNECT

Tags: php, mysqli

How I can recompile and reinstall mysqli php lib with flag MYSQLI_NO_CHANGE_USER_ON_PCONNECT on Centos linux?

Comment: What part of the recompilation do you have problems with? The flag seems [well described in the mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqlnd.persist.html). How is your question specific to CentOS ?

Comment: I can't find src of mysql to configure.. 
I traied get  mysql-5.6.25.tar.gz, unzip, go to  mysql-5.6.25 and run:
CFLAGS="-DMYSQLI_NO_CHANGE_USER_ON_PCONNECT" ./configure --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql/ --with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --enable-debug && make clean && make -j6 and I get error: bash: ./configure:  no such file

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against it.

There is no gain that it's worth even trouble with recompiling, not to mention disastrous consequences. This behavior has been added for a reason.